# How can I create dropdown list inside table?

Tags: vue.js, html-table, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I'm trying to add a table in Vue. How can I create dropdown list inside each table row just like in an example below?
I have some dificulties with making a list position: 'absolute'.

Is there a component that can do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it can simply be solve by boostrap, add boostrap codes like this

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

according to your image it is simple a dropdown

Comment: It's not working. The dropdown still makes the table scroll. I want the dropdown to be position absolute

Comment: ......My bad. It's working fine, I just had an element with overflow before.

Comment: add this `<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-start">` then the dropdwon will stay as you want. dropdown is not something you can achive with Vue, it boostrap that will solve the problem